# Lost phone storage and external storage after editing vold.fstab file

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I have a Micromax Canvas Juice A177. Because it has a very small internal memory, I tried to swap the external SD with internal SD.

### What I did

I rooted my phone and then I installed ES File Explorer, then I edited the `/etc/vold.fstab` file and replaced sdcard0 with sdcard1 and sdcard1 with sdcard0. Then I reboot my phone .

### What happened

I checked the storage and my phone storage was changed to SD card but total memory was still 700mb (as it was before). I then edited the vold.fstab file once again.

After that, when I checked the storage it showed as:

```
  PHONE STORAGE
  ________________

  SD CARD
  ________________
  Mount SD card
  Insert an SD card for mounting
```

I had my SD card inserted, but it still said "Insert an SD card for mounting". When I opened the File Manager it was showing an empty folder (no phone storage, no SD card). Then I performed a factory reset.

### The situation now

Phone Storage is showing the same thing (file manager as well). All the installed apps are deleted ,only the system apps are present with SuperSU. I don't have phone storage (only internal storage) and the external SD card is not working.

When I connected my phone to my PC using a USB cable, it is not showing the phone memory.

As you can see I have probably destroyed my phone, and I may not get any benefit from the warranty because I've rooted it. Is there any possible way to get my phone back to its previous state? I tried some tips from the Internet to connect via USB debugging with the Android SDK but it didn't work.

Comment: Come on, don't abuse formatting features like that. It doesn't make your question _more_ readable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should download the stock ROM:

[XDA Forum - Micromax Canvas Juice A77 [Root, Recovery, Roms, Etc][MTK6572]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49018875&postcount=3)

After that, if you only changed that file, you can extract it from stock rom and replace it in your phone (check to assign the right permissions), factory reset and your phone should work again.

If it's still not working you can flash the whole ROM.

BTW Factory Reset only resets your /data partition it doesn't change /system because that's not supposed to change at all, so factory reset will never restore files in /system. It's always better to backup the original files before you change anything.

Comment: My device is Micromax Canvas Juice A177 not A77. 
 Will this work ?

Comment: Probably not, sorry I didn't read it correctly. Anyway same explanation just download the ROM for your phone www.needrom.com/download/micromax-a177-2/

Comment: ok thanx....
 Can i simply change the file i edited ?
 will that work ?

Comment: np, if you only changed that file restoring it and restarting should solve your problem. If not try a factory reset too. If it's still not working there must be something else changed so, unless you know what it is, you'll have to flash stock rom. Remember to check user/group and permissions are correct after you restore the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this modded `vold.fstab`. Do not delete the file, instead copy & paste the content with this, then reboot the device.

```
## Vold 2.0 Generic fstab
## - San Mehat (san@android.com)
## 

#######################
## Regular device mount
##
## Format: dev_mount <label> <mount_point> <part> <sysfs_path1...> 
## label        - Label for the volume
## mount_point  - Where the volume will be mounted
## part         - Partition # (1 based), or 'auto' for first usable partition.
## <sysfs_path> - List of sysfs paths to source devices
######################

## Example of a standard sdcard mount for the emulator / Dream
# Mounts the first usable partition of the specified device
dev_mount sdcard /storage/sdcard1 emmc@fat /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host
dev_mount sdcard2 /storage/sdcard0 auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.1 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host
## Example of a dual card setup
# dev_mount left_sdcard  /mnt/sdcard0  auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/mtk-sd.0/mmc_host/mmc0
# dev_mount right_sdcard /mnt/sdcard2  auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.1 /devices/platform/mtk-sd.2/mmc_host/mmc2

## Example of specifying a specific partition for mounts
# dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard 2 /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/msm_sdcc.2/mmc_host/mmc1
```